# Ploting/Drawing a chessboard with customized color in each cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am looking for a Python function to draw/plot a chessboard with a customized number of cells and customized colors in each cell. The script can be based on the `matplotlib`, which I actually prefer.

It would be great if I deal with colors instead of a heatmap. For instance, it would be great if I can use this function something like this:

```
# Coding in Python:
#chess[row,col] = color;
chess[0,0] = yellow;
chess[0,3] = black;
```

Something similar to below:

[image]

It would be great if the implementation is parameterized.

Comment: You appear to be asking for finished code, which is well beyond the Stack Overflow scope.  Given your comment to the first-posted answer (only one, at this writing), you're also asking for tutorial support -- which, again, is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the RGB values of the colors, and then use `imshow`

For example:

```
import numpy as np
yellow=(255,255,0)
red=(255,0,0)
blue=(0,0,255)
board=np.array([[yellow,red,blue],[blue,yellow,red]])
plt.imshow(board)
```

will yield:

[image: board]

Comment: Thanks @Binyamin. Can you please tell me how can I add borders between boxes? And also how can I remove the ticks from the X and Y axes?

Comment: For the ticks you can simply add `plt.axis('off')`. For the borders - I don't know.